# update custom metadata types :getting error

Tags: apex, custom, custom-metadata

I need to update the value in custom metadata type when ever the class called/invoked. I am getting error like field is not writable even though permission is there,here family id is number data types

```
global class Docketnumbertag
{
    @InvocableMethod
    public static List<string> updatefamilid()
    {
        List<SymphonyIPM__Docket_Number_Tags__mdt> Docketnumbertag = [SELECT
            Id, 
            SymphonyIPM__Family_ID__c
        FROM
            SymphonyIPM__Docket_Number_Tags__mdt];
        for(SymphonyIPM__Docket_Number_Tags__mdt addfamilyid: Docketnumbertag)
        {
            addfamilyid.SymphonyIPM__Family_ID__c = addfamilyid.SymphonyIPM__Family_ID__c + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom metadata is not updateable using DML, You can only do that by using the Metadata API however you can retrive it using  SOQL query.